# c# show underscore _ in date instead of dash -

Tags: c#

I am saving a file name with a string value plus the date as follows:

```
var fileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}.zip", "fileName", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

The above line gives me:

```
fileName_2015-11-24.zip
```

Is it some how possible that I can get `fileName_2015_11_24.zip`

I have actually tried with `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")` But I forgot to mention in my question.

One possibility is to replace dashed `-` with underscores `_` but is there any other solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to replace `-` with `_` in your filenames, but don't want to replace `-` with `_`. Seems legit :)

Comment: Clearly shows you have not tried anything. It's a surprising question at such a reputation level.

Comment: In what way didn't `ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")` work?

Comment: @Richard I used this `ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")` and still I was seeing the `-` in the file name. That was the main reason I put my question.

Comment: If your dashes are in the file's name, you'll have to replace them with underscores. Date formatting will format the date... not the 'filename'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
String.Format("{0}_{1:yyyy_MM_dd}", "filename", DateTime.Now);
```

To clarify: You can use DateTime format parameters in String.Format itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `-` with `_`

```
var fileName = String.Format("fileName_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"));
```

Comment: `String.Format("fileName_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"));` ?

Comment: `String.Format("{0}_{1:yyyy_MM_dd}.zip", filename, DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply using underscores in your date format string?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide formatting parameters for each value in your call to String.Format. Just add a custom formatting string after a colon (`:`), like this:

```
var fileName = String.Format("fileName_{0:yyyy_MM_dd}.zip", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
 $"FileName_{DateTime.Now:MM_dd_yyyy}";
```